# post a form using ajax and returning the results to span or div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to submit a form using ajax and return the results to the same page using innerHTML. But it seems the input value on the form is not getting passed to the action which is a php.

Here is my html form

```
<form id="check" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkFunction();">
                    <p>
                        <label for="store">Type Store Number to check:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="store" name="storenum" maxlength="4"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="return checkFunction();"/>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

This is where I would like the results returned on the same page

```
<span id="results"></span>
```

And this is how I put together the ajax call

```
function checkFunction(){
        var ajaxRequest;  

        try{
                // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
                // Internet Explorer Browsers
                try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                        try{
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e){
                                alert("Your browser broke!");
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        }
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
        }
        ajaxRequest.open("POST","run.php",true);
        ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

And this is how the php action file put together

```
<?php
$storeNum = $_POST['storenum'];

echo "<pre>Store number: " . $storeNum . "</pre>";
$pingresult = shell_exec("./ping_isp.sh $storeNum");
echo "<pre>$pingresult</pre>";
if (strpos($pingresult, 'ISP was unreachable') == true) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("ISP not available")';
echo '</script>';
die();
}
echo "<br>";

?>
```

If I use directly the php on the form as action let say like below it works perfectly

```
<form id="check" method="POST">
                    <p>
                        <label for="store">Type Store Number to check:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="store" name="storenum" maxlength="4"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Check" formaction="run.php"/>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

But this will return the results on another page. I would like to get the results returned on the same page. Hope you guys can help me out on this.

Comment: I believe the problem is you're not passing your arguments to you php page, you're just calling the page with no POST values.

Comment: try changing `ajaxRequest.send();` to `ajaxRequest.send("storenum=" + yourstrorevalue);`

Comment: Sending user input direct to the shell can be very dangerous.

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd yes. what am i doing wrong on the ajax call? not really sure how to do it using jquery ajax post if that is an alternative way

Comment: @chris85 i have a separate jquery validation to accept values that is only needed which is 4 digit number. not really fullproof but it helps

Comment: Client validation does nothing server side. I just access URL direct with CURL and can make your server do as I please. Why not use jQuery ajax if already using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agreee with @chris85, this could be dangerous to do. In any event, to answer your question I've made the changes to your code that I believe you need...

```
function checkFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  

    try{
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                    try{
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e){
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                    }
            }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
    }

    var storevalue = document.getElementByID("storenum").value;
    ajaxRequest.open("POST","run.php",true);
    ajaxRequest.send("storenum=" + storevalue);
}
```

Please forgive me if I've made any slight mistakes in coding, this is untested and it's possible I made a typo that I've missed.

**EDIT: I had a little more time this morning than yesterday, so I took your code and reworked it a bit. The version below now works and should give you the result you're looking for.**

```
function checkFunction(){
    var xmlhttpmod;
    var storevalue = document.getElementByID("store").value;


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpmod=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpmod=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttpmod.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttpmod.readyState==4 && xmlhttpmod.status==200)  {
            // console.log(xmlhttpmod.responseText);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlhttpmod.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttpmod.open("POST","test.php",true);
    xmlhttpmod.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttpmod.send("storenum="+storevalue);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still unsuccessful. I also tried using var storevalue = document.getElementByID("store").value; since that is the id of the element but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, i should have used "store" not "storenum". I would put a `print_r($_POST); exit;` at the top of my php page to see what values are being passed to determine where my error was (note this information will show up back on your main page in the responseText, in your case the contents of your "results" element.)

Comment: i did your suggestion and i am only getting 'Array ( )' on the results element. Still figuring out why because it is already indicated to store the value of the element with id 'store'.

Comment: @Dren, please see the edit to my post, it should solve your problem

Comment: your modified ajax code correctly receives the input from the form and passes it to the php but i am not getting the results passed to the span/div element. i tried changing this line document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText; to document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlhttpmod.responseText; but still not getting the response back to the page.

Comment: @Dren You were correct to change that line, that was an error on my part. Try commenting out that line and uncommenting the line above that outputs to the console.log See if that outputs the result you're looking for. Maybe your PHP page isn't outputting what you think it is.

Comment: i made some changes on the php to be able to print the output it works perfectly now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this and post your results please

```
 <form id="check" method="POST">
     <p>
      <label for="store">Type Store Number to check:</label>
      <input type="text" id="store" name="storenum" maxlength="4"/>
     </p>
     <p>
      <input type="button" value="Check" id="submitMyForm"/>
     </p>
<div id="response"></div>
</form>
```

your php file:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $required = array('storenum');
    $error = false;
    foreach($required as $key){
        if(empty($_POST[$key])){    
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$error){
        // process data or whatever you need
    }
    else{
        echo 'empty field error';
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: ../login.php");
}
```

and your ajax

```
    $('#submitMyForm').on('submit', function(){
    var thisForm = $(this),
        url = thisForm.attr('action'),
        type = thisForm.attr('method'),
        data = {};
    thisForm.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){    
        var thisField = $(this),
            name = thisField.attr('name'),
            value = thisField.val();
            data[name] = value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            $('#response').hide().html(response).fadeIn(700);
        },
        error: function(){  
            $('#response').hide().html('<span class="label label-danger">Ocurrió un error desconocido</span>').fadeIn(700); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```